# How to check pair of brackets condition using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a java script in which I want to validate numbers of following format:

```
555-555-5555 
(555)-555-5555
```

For this, I am using following regular expression:

```
/\(?(\d{3}\)?)[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})/
```

But this is giving true for following expression which is wrong:

```
(555 - 555 5555
```

I want to make this regular expression to check if opening bracket is present then closing bracket must be present and vice versa. What changes should I do in my RE to make it achieve my goal?

Comment: Why are you doing this validation? Who cares? Why are you harassing the user to match his parens?

Comment: What is expected result for `(555)5555555`?

Comment: @guest271314 it should be true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the braces are optional `?`-zero or one occurrence, the regex is allowing `(` and/or `)` brace. OR condition in the regex can be use to match either three numbers or three numbers in brackets.

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hXN4sh/1)

```
(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})
^               ^ : Group
 ^^     ^^        : Matches ( & ) respectively
          ^       : OR condition in regex
   ^^^^^   ^^^^^  : Match three digits
```

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input pattern="(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})" />
```

Comment: why are you using `[- ]?` and not simply `-`?

Comment: @Huntro The numbers can be separated by space or hyphen `-` or none of them. The character class `[- ]?` allows `-` or ` `(space) zero or once.

Comment: Not certain what expected result for `(555)5555555` is though note `RegExp` would return true for that input string as well

Comment: @guest271314 Don't know about that but from the OP's regex looks like it should return true. Also, the question is about the brackets only. I haven't changed other parts in regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` `/^(\(\d{3}\)|^\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{4}$/` to match three digits within parenthesis or without parenthesis, e.g., `"(555)"` or `"555"`, at beginning of string, followed by `"-"` followed by three digits, followed by `"-"` followed by four digits followed by end of input

```js
var re = /^(\(\d{3}\)|^\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
console.log(re.test("(555-555-5555")); // false
console.log(re.test("555-555-5555")); // true
console.log(re.test("(555)-555-5555")); // true
```

`

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a graceful way to do this with regex, just repeat yourself.

```
/(?:\((\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})/
```

The change is that I replaced `\(?(\d{3})\)?` with `(?:\((\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))`. The initial `?:` causes the overarching group not to be captured, then you have `\((\d{3})\)` OR `(\d{3})`.

Since empty capturing groups are given as the empty string, you can then get the value of the first three numbers - whether it was the first or second group that captured them - with `$1$2`.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late in the party but I assume it is one of the freecodecamp challenge. So, additionally if you want to check for the code then here is my version of solution.

```
  let telRegex = /^\+?[1{1}]?[- ]?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
```

it will check for the code number specified(here the code is 1 for the challenge) and an additional check for + infront of the phone number.